# Where do you put the "main function" of a Python app?

Tags: python, project-structure, packages, file-structure, entry-point

Suppose you are developing a Python standalone application (not a library).

1. Would you make it a Python package? Or just files next to each other?
2. If you would make it a package, what would be the "starting point" file (where the first line of code runs)? The `__init__.py`? Or a short "startup" script outside the package which calls a function in the package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the whole application fits into a single file, that is the most simple solution.

Otherwise, it is best to create a complete package. When you create a setuptools-based `setup.py` file, you can [define various entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) that should be installed as scripts. However, these entry points refer to functions, not files.

Instead of running a script with Python (`python path/to/script.py args...`), you can also run a module or package: `python -m example.package args...`. For modules (i.e. Python files), you have to do the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check and dispatch to your main function. For packages (i.e. directories with an `__init__.py` file), you have to create a `__main__.py` file as an entry point. It makes sense to put the argument parsing & user interface code here.

This is particularly sensible when adding a command line interface to an existing library. However, it is often elegant to write the central behaviour of an application as a library, and then only wrap that library with a simple user interface. In particular, this layered architecture makes unit testing easier.

Comment: So to summarize, for a standalone app you suggest making it a package, and putting the 'main' function - the code which is supposed to run first - in  the `__main__.py` file?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes, that's probably the best solution when the app consists of multiple files.